# Set specific timezone globally for app to use

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I'm writing an app that needs to display and calculate all dates, times, timeintervals etc. from a specific, given timezone in Europe. Meaning, if I'm, say, in Paris, the app works flawlessly now, but if I go to New York, the app should display and work exactly as if I were still in Paris.

Naively, I tried (in the `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` function)

```
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/Paris"]];
```

but of course that doesn't work, all my NSDateFormatter objects still use the current timezone if not explicitly told otherwise.

So, what I'd like to know is:

- Is there any way to globally enforce a timezone in an app? I'd rather not go through all my code and fix every single date formatter and date picker and so on if there's another way.
- Will `[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/Paris"]` properly switch between CET and CEST?

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the method [`+ (void)setDefaultTimeZone:(NSTimeZone *)aTimeZone`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000190-CJGEADHD) of the class `NSTimeZone`.

Comment: ... alright, now I feel stupid :-) I accepted your answer, but could you maybe just add what you think about the CET/CEST issue? Thanks very much!

Comment: Yes, I think it does switch automatically by default.

Comment: In which function i have to write this function ?